# SQLite android - Select records within the last year

Tags: android-sqlite

i'm getting the sum() of the records of one month in this  year.. here it is the method to get the month , but how can i get only the month of this year and not from the last year?

```
public Cursor calculate(String month){
        return db.rawQuery("Select " + "sum(" + CN_GA + ")" +
                " from " + TABLE_NAME + " where strftime('%m', " + CN_DATE + ") = '" + month +"'", null);
    }
```

Note: mi date is in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format.

thx for the answer in advance , and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine with the condition

```
where strftime('%Y', yourdate) = "2015"
```

That is

```
" where strftime('%Y:%m', " + CN_DATE + ") = " 
  + "'" + year + ":" + month + "'"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! , But when we are in 2016 , 2015 records show ... I need that always give the last year. then when we are in 2016 , only the 2016 show

Comment: Assign the year you want to the 'year' variable.

Comment: the only way to do this is giving the option to the user to choose?

Comment: Get the date from the system....
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28%29

Comment: i understand you now , but i tryed and give me this sql error: SQLiteException: unrecognized token: ":" (code 1):... any idea why is this?

Comment: it works , thx for your help , the error was my mistake ,(doing 'year':'month' )